# Add multiple views to layout programatically - only 1 view is visible

Tags: android, view, addition

The problem is that only the first view is visible. If I add view 1 before view 2, only view 1 is visible. If I add view 2 before view 1, only view 2 is visible. I did try to setVisibility but...no lucks :(

Here's my code:

```
   LinearLayout ver_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        ver_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    //create an image view
    ImageView iv_ava = new ImageView(this);
    iv_ava.setImageResource(R.drawable.sss);
    // add it to my vertical layout
    ver_layout.addView(iv_ava, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //create a text view
    TextView tv_name = new TextView(this);
    tv_name.setText("testing");
    //add it to my vertical layout
    ver_layout.addView(tv_name, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //after adding 2 views to a vertical layout, I add that layout to a 
    //horizontal linear layout, which is a layout defined in xml
    LinearLayout hori_layout = (LinearLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.hori_layout);
    hori_layout.addView(ver_layout, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Where do you create `iv_ava` and `tv_name`?

Comment: Has the ver_layout wrap_content?

Comment: I create iv_ava and tv_name with code (I edited). I already tried to set ver_layout wrap_content with  
ver_layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); .... still the same

Answer (score 1):

After hours looking through my code, I realized I had imported the wrong LayoutParams. It's supposed to be android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams not android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams